# how to compare two fields from the list with Contains

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to compare 2 fields from the list with another field, but in my case, only one field is compared

```
var compaer = model.ActionList.Where(i => !accessActionsList.Select(l => l.ActionName).Contains(i.AccessActionName));
```

But I want to compare two fields with two others in this way

```
 var compaer = model.ActionList.Where(i => !accessActionsList.Select(l => new(l.ActionName , l.ControllName)).Contains(i.AccessActionName , i.ControllerName));
```

Comment: You could implement `IEquatable` for the Action class, or create a separate class that implements `IComparer` and pass it in to the `Contains` method, or use `.Any(predicate)` instead of `.Contains()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tuples.

```
class class1 
{
    public required string prop1 { get; set; }
    public required string prop2 { get; set; }
}
class class2
{
    public required string prop3 { get; set; }
    public required string prop4 { get; set; }
}


var list1 = new List<class1> { new class1 { prop1="a", prop2="b" }, new class1 { prop1 = "c", prop2 = "d" }, new class1 { prop1 = "e", prop2 = "f" } };
var list2 = new List<class2> { new class2 { prop3 = "a", prop4 = "BBB" }, new class2 { prop3 = "AAA", prop4 = "d" }, new class2 { prop3 = "e", prop4 = "f" } };

var x = list1.Where (a=> list2.Select(b=>(b.prop3,b.prop4)).Contains((a.prop1,a.prop2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try as below:

```
var actionlist=new List<ControllerActionEntity>()
            {
                new ControllerActionEntity(){AccessActionName="Action",AccessControllerName="Controller",ActionName="Action1",ControllerName="Controller1"},
                new ControllerActionEntity(){AccessActionName="Action2",AccessControllerName="Controller2",ActionName="Action2",ControllerName="Controller2"},
                new ControllerActionEntity(){AccessActionName="Action4",AccessControllerName="Controller4",ActionName="Action3",ControllerName="Controller3"},
                new ControllerActionEntity(){AccessActionName="Action1",AccessControllerName="Controller4",ActionName="Action4",ControllerName="Controller4"}
            };

            


var targetlist = (from first in actionlist
                               where !actionlist.Any(second => second.ActionName == first.AccessActionName && second.ControllerName == first.AccessControllerName) select first).ToList();
```

When I debug:

[image]